# Problem using command brownie bake nft-mix

Tags: chainlink

im having an error when use command brownie bake nft-mix for the example data in Patrick tutorial, just installed Visual Studio Code, then Phyton from their website, then buildtools for C++ libraries and i have this error:

```
>brownie bake nft-mix
Brownie v1.1.0 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Downloading from https://github.com/brownie-mix/nft-mix/archive/master.zip...
  File "...\python\python36\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 55, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{args['<command>']}").main()
  File "..\python\python36\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\bake.py", line 27, in main
    path = project.from_brownie_mix(args["<mix>"], args["<path>"], args["--force"])
  File "..\python\python36\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 293, in from_brownie_mix
    with zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(request.content)) as zf:
  File "..\python\python36\lib\zipfile.py", line 1131, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "..\programs\python\python36\lib\zipfile.py", line 1198, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're seeing this... but for the meantime you could just run

```
git clone https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/nft-mix
cd nft-mix
```

And that will have the same affect.